# Bokeh plot is not being embedded into html

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I am trying to simply load my /plot/ webpage from the code below, however, the bokeh plot is not being embedded in the webpage. Note, in newer versions of bokeh, it does not require a css file (from the CDN_css).
When using the output_file and show methods, I can easily get a separate webpage to spawn a html of the bokeh plot. However, when attempting to embed it, I merely get the html code from index, without the embedded chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

'''python code: app.py'''

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def create_plot(ticker):
    global p
    ts = TimeSeries(key="**********", output_format='pandas')
    data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=ticker,interval='1min', outputsize='full')
    data = data.iloc[::-1]
    #gets the #tsla data from the API and orders it in reverese (5 days from most recent entry to furthest)

    data["datetime"] = data.index #adds a datetime column of the index strings (need to convert to datetime objects)

    datetime_list = []
    for i in data["datetime"]:
        datetime_list.append(datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

    data["datetime"] = datetime_list #converts the datetime column from a str to a datetime object column

    my_data = pd.DataFrame()

    my_data["datetime"] = data["datetime"]
    my_data["stock_price"] = data["1. open"]

    last_time = my_data["datetime"][0]
    one_day_ago = last_time - relativedelta(days=1)

    daily_data = my_data[my_data["datetime"] > one_day_ago]

    #bokeh chart
    p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime",plot_width=1000, plot_height=400)

    p.sizing_mode="scale_width"
    p.title.text="# " + ticker +  " Stock Price"
    p.title.text_color="navy"
    p.title.text_font="times"
    p.title.text_font_style="bold"
    p.title.text_font_size="28pt"
    p.title.vertical_align="top"
    p.title.align="center"
    p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color=None
    p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color=None
    p.xaxis.axis_label="Time"
    p.yaxis.axis_label="Price USD"
    p.xaxis.axis_label_text_color="navy"
    p.yaxis.axis_label_text_color="navy"
    p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style="bold"
    p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_style="bold"
    p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font="times"
    p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font="times"
    p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "16pt"
    p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "16pt"
    p.ygrid.band_fill_alpha = 0.1
    p.ygrid.band_fill_color = "navy"
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None


    p.line(daily_data["datetime"], daily_data["stock_price"], line_width=2, color="blue")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/plot/")
def plot():
    create_plot("TSLA")
    script1,div1 = components(p) # script_1 is the js source code, div_1 is the html source code

    cdn_js = CDN.js_files[0] #need first element of this list
    return render_template("plot.html",script1=script1, div1=div1, cdn_js=cdn_js)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

'''home.html code'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">
    <title>Daniel's #tsla chart webapp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Daniel's #TSLA chart webapp</h1>
    <h2>Hi, welcome to my stock market webapp which gives an analysis of #TSLA</h2>
    <p>To proceed, please press the button below</p>
    <form class="input" action="plot.html" method="post">
      Please enter your email address below to access the #TSLA market data! <br>
      <input type="submit" name="name_submission" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

'''plot.html code'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src={{CDN_js | safe}}></script>
    <title>Daniel's #tsla chart webapp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Daniel's #TSLA chart webapp</h1>
    <h2>Hi, welcome to my stock market webapp which gives an analysis of #TSLA</h2>
    {{ script1|safe }}
    {{ div1|safe }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The form action is `"plot.html"` but the Flask endpoint is `/plot/` which does not seem to line up. Are there any Flask errors reported? What about if you just navigate to `/plot/` directly?

Comment: Navigating to /plot/ shows the h1 and h2 tag text of the plot.html file. However, it does not show the embedded bokeh plot. No flask errors are being shown, as the html is actually loading, just without the embedded plot.

Comment: Any JavaScript console errors?

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: could it be a problem with the newly released version of bokeh (released late August I believe)

Comment: I just tested the project examples for `components` from the repo and they work as expected, and `components` is also maintained under heavy testing, so it doesn't seem the most likely explanation. Perhaps it might be helpful to start from a working example and nudge it towards your specific needs? The basic repo example is here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_multiple.py